Shading problems with object
How can I fix the shading problems in Blender 4.0?
Here are screenshots of the object grid and the place where the shading behaves incorrectly:



Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

Please verbally describe what your issue is, be specific and and use relevant keywords. Avoid referencing images or links as alternative to words, try to stay away from vague references like "this happens", "issue with", "like so", which make the post impossible to find for someone using search. Instead describe what "it" is, be descriptive, succinct and detailed. It may not be immediately obvious to users trying to help what you mean. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

As you can see, the bad shading happens exactly at those vertices where 5 edges come together (a so-called E-pole). Very sharp angles in topology tend to cause problems.
In this case, it could be because the edges are not actually at the exact same level. You can fix this by selecting all the vertices on that level (the top surface from which the protrusions extend), pressing S to scale, pressing Z to lock in the vertical axis, and pressing 0 to 'equalize' them.
An option that's probably better is to retopologize those areas.

If a pole is changing the curvature of the surface, then it should be removed or eliminated.
source


The edges indicated with red need to go. The green edges are a suggestion for the middle parts, but for those near the edge of the mesh I can't think of a proper solution (that keeps your quad-only topology intact, at least, and doesn't add extra loops). You can experiment with several options and see what works best.
The article from which I quoted has insightful tips and options. Here is another helpful thread on BlenderArtists.

Pressing S 0 to scale all vertices on some level without constraining the scaling to a specific axis (for example Z which seems appropriate in this case) will make all vertices be put in the exact same location, not just the same level.

Thanks, @GordonBrinkmann! I had completely forgotten that important step :)

Dont forget your supporting edge loops! even if your floor is perfectly flat, it wont shade correctly with smooth shading without supporting edge loops. example
